# Error in library(reshape2) : there is no package called ‘reshape2’

Tags: r

Although I installed the 'reshape2' packages, it does not run when I type `library(reshape2)`. Also, I can not see the package in the package list. I can see it in the directory where packages are stored. (For example: `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library`) But it is not shown in the RStudio as packages, and I cannot use it. How can I install it correctly?

My `.libPaths()` is:

```
"C:/Users/batuh/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library"
```

When I type `install.packages("reshape2")`, it says:

```
package ‘reshape2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘reshape2’
```

Comment: Apparently you are using another library. What is the output of `.libPaths()`?

Comment: It is "C:/Users/batuh/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library".

I can see the 'reshape2' package in the first directory but not on the rstudio. (I can only see 'reshape' package. In the second directory, there are short of packages; I guess it is that of System Library.

Comment: I noticed that whenever I type install.packages("reshape2"), it says package ‘reshape2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘reshape2’

Comment: I'm voting to migrate your question to [SO] where it may get a better answer. You might just want to delete your library and start fresh, or delete the reshape2 package from the first library path manually.

Comment: Solved it as you said, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 2):

Here how I solved the problem:

I terminated all R sessions from task manager. There were at least 8 of them running simultaneously even though I closed Rstudio.

Then I deleted the `reshape2` folder from my library directory, which you can reach by `.libPaths()` function.

There will be 2 directories, the first one is where the package should be stored. For example:

```
C:/Users/batuh/Documents/R/win-library/3.5
```

Then I restarted Rstudio and installed it without problems.

Answer (score 1):

install.packages("reshape2") will work if you are using it for the first time in RStudio

Comment: Hello! Make sure your answer actually answers the question, otherwise you are at risk of receiving a down vote and losing reputation points. Read more about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. First I ran, in the R studio console, `remove.packages("reshape2")`. When it was done removing reshape2, I reinstalled it by running `install.packages("reshape2")` in R studio console. I then restarted R and the code running reshape2 worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I just download the package of "reshape2" and fix the problem.

```
install.packages("reshape2")
```